# Cordova asking for location but I don't have geolocation plugin

Tags: cordova

Cordova is asking for a location, even though I don't have geolocation plugin.

Comment: What actually do you want, if you dont have geolocation plugin install.

Comment: That's the problem it's asking for permission altough i dont have it - i dont want it to ask permission! Maybe its problem with Intel XDK, because i am using that platform

Answer (score 0):

You're not providing much in the way of details, but, based on the information you have provided, it feels like geolocation is enabled in the app manifest - and that's why the app is asking for permission.